# Crear servicio que ejecute npm start

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu, npm, servicio, babel

Hola amigos de la comunidad.

Tengo un proyecto hecho node.js en react y express y quiero desplegarlo en una maquina virtual con ubuntu 16.04 creando un servicio que ejecute **npm start**.

En mi pc ejecuto el proyecto con **npm start** que a su vez ejecuta **babel-node /bin/www**. */bin/www* es el script de inicio del proyecto. En el servidor lo ejecuto de igual manera.

El asunto es: cómo puedo crear un servicio que ejecute **npm start** al iniciarse la máquina en el directorio del proyecto y que lo mantenga activo sin la necesidad de tener que iniciarlo yo.

Gracias

Answer (score 2):

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es usando [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), así puedes gestionar tus procesos en nodejs ;)

- Instalar

`npm install -g pm2`

- Ejecutar tu script

`pm2 start npm -- start`

- Luego de tener la app corriendo

`pm2 save`

- Finalmente, generas y ejecutar el startup script

`pm2 startup`